# java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: java, rest

when I user Response as a return, an exception occurred. This is my code

```
@POST
@Path("/checkyzm")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public String checkyzm(String param);

@GET
@Path("/qryUserInfo")
public Response qryUserInfo(@CookieParam("loginTicket") Cookie cookie);
```

and the error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.core.Response
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.qryUserInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Comment: there is no IS-A relationship between String and Response.  You either need to return a String, or put the String in a response

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, I found that AOP intercepted the request and processed the output